# Show full URI/URL in Firefox developer tools console tab

Tags: ajax, firefox, firebug, firefox-developer-tools

I have always relied on the Firebug console tab within Firefox to display complete ajax calls, my systems all use ajax extensively and its useful to be able to monitor the calls in one listing. Ive always found Firebug to be the most complete version of this, and it is this one feature that has prevented me from migrating to any other browser including FFs own developer console, where the only way to determine the endpoints is to hover over the request, or spend two mouse clicks on opening up the response panel followed by the "Params" tab. Neither of these are very useful in a working environment.

In the latest FF however, I find that Firebug is deprecated in favour of the built in developer console, so I figure that if Firebug is to disappear, there must be a way to configure the replacement to my liking.

Heres an example output side by side, the right hand side (Firebug) displays not only the endpoint but all parameters right in the line, for example "ajax.php?home&act=counters", whereas the left hand side (built in console) simply displays "ajax.php" for all calls.

[image: Side by Side comparison, Firefox vs Firebug]

Answer (score 6):

The URL parameters are displayed for requests logged to the console [since Firefox 60](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1335316).

[image]
In case the URL isn't shown completely (due to the width of the window being too small), the URL is cropped, though you can still see the complete URL when hovering the request.

Furthermore, the URL parameters are also displayed within the [Network Monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor).

[image: URL parameter shown in Network Monitor]